# Pandas | Use groupby to find duplicate based on 2 columns which have NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the following DataFrame where there are duplicates of the same person.

```
colnames = ["person", "ig_handle", "email", "phone_number"]
data = [
    ["emma", '@emma', 'emma@gmail.com', np.nan],
    ["emma", '@emma', np.nan, "09-emma-number"],
    ["jean", '@jean', "jean@gmail.com", np.nan],
    ["jean", '@jean', np.nan, np.nan],
    ["kate", '@kate', "kate@gmail.com", np.nan],
    ["john", '@john1', "john1@gmail.com", "09-john-number"],
    ["john", '@john1', np.nan, "09-john-number-new"],
    ["john", np.nan, "john1@gmail.com", np.nan],
    ["john", '@john2', np.nan, np.nan],
    ["lily", np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=colnames)
df
```

We can identify duplicates by either `ig_handle` or `email`. Example: There are 2 **john**'s but they have different `ig_handle`.

Some rows have the data the other row doesn't have. For example, **emma** on first row has `email` but the second row doesn't.

I want to eliminate duplicate rows by merging the data together.

So the end result would be as below:

```
person   ig_handle  email            phone_number
emma     @emma      emma@gmail.com   09-emma-number
jean     @jean      jean@gmail.com   NaN
kate     @kate      kate@gmail.com   NaN
john     @john1     john1@gmail.com  09-join-number-new
john     @john2     NaN              NaN
lily     NaN        NaN              NaN
```

Comment: what should be the result for `john` person (in rows) ?

Comment: Thanks, my bad. I've added the desired result for clarity. @RomanPerekhrest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.groupby(['person',df['ig_handle'].fillna('@' + df['email'].str.split('@').str[0])],as_index=False,dropna=False).last()
```

Output:

```
  person ig_handle            email        phone_number
0   emma     @emma   emma@gmail.com      09-emma-number
1   jean     @jean   jean@gmail.com                None
2   john    @john1  john1@gmail.com  09-john-number-new
3   john    @john2             None                None
4   kate     @kate   kate@gmail.com                None
5   lily      None             None                None
```